# how to get the series name, id and title value dynamically from highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

[JSFiddle Link for the charts](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/28/)

```
        if (chart.length == 3) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {

                chart[i].renderer
                .image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png',chart[i].chartWidth - 40, 5, 20, 20)
                .add()
                .css({'cursor' : 'pointer'})
                .attr({'title' : 'Charts'})
                .on('click', function() {
                    alert("hi");console.log(chart[i]);
                            //var chartValue = $('#'+id).highcharts();
                            //var series = chartValue.series[1]; 
                            //console.log(series.name + "...hi" +series.title);
                });
            }
        }
```

How can we get the charts details on click event?

Comment: How is that image connected to any of the series? In general you have access to all series via: `charts[i].series[j].name/id/options/etc.`

Comment: is there any other way to connect to the chart using renderer method?

Comment: This solution is perfectly fine, I think. What is wrong? In click event you have access to all properties in a chart using `charts[i]`. Only problem you have is with closures, see fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/29/

Comment: Thank you @PawełFus; Is there any other way to connect to chart without using renderer method? I checked with API for event options but it wasn't of much help...

Comment: @PawełFus I just modified the http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/31/ my question here is once I load new chart how do I make the image button click to work as back button? which loads back the 3 charts back?

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/36/

Comment: @PawełFus I just altered the code a bit, and I used the highcharts event method to perform the on click action than using the LOOPing logic...http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/38/ but how do I toggle back to earlier charts?

Comment: The same way - just add additional parameter in `addChart` for function which will be different in order to chart which should be rendered.